# Filtering by relation count in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm using the SQLAlchemy Python ORM in a Pylons project. I have a class "Project" which has a one to many relationship with another class "Entry". I want to do a query in SQLAlchemy that gives me all of the projects which have one or more entries associated with them. At the moment I'm doing:

```
[project for project in Session.query(Project) if len(project.entries)>0]
```

which I know isn't ideal, but I can't figure out how to do a filter that does what I require (e.g. Session.query(Project).filter(Project.entries.exists())).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Session.query(Project).filter(Project.entries.any())` should work.

Edited credit of James Brady's comment, be sure to give him some love.

Comment: as in, Session.query(Project).filter(Project.entries.any())

Comment: How would you get Projects with more than 1 entry?

Comment: @Jugdish try this `session.query(Parent).join(Child).group_by(Parent.id).having(func.count(Child.id) > 1)`